# In which cases will async methods be continued in a different thread than the thread used before calling the await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I learned that async methods are not necessarily continued in the same thread as they were started, after calling an await.

What are the particular cases when an async flow is continued in another thread?

Is it possible to force that all async methods in a call tree are extecuted in the same thread? (I don't need this, but just want to get the understanding, why that might not be possible...)

I know that in case of an existing SynchronizationContext the original thread will be used again after the await, if ConfigureAwait(false) is not called. That is not the topic of this question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "What are the particular cases when an async flow is continued in another thread" when the original Thread is busy with something else

Comment: So, if the calling thread is busy, another worker thread from the pool is used, and if it is not busy, the original calling thread will be used?

Comment: No, that's too simplistic. What threads get drafted into service for what depends on 1) the way the async code is written (it may *choose* to run synchronously, if the result is immediately available) and 2) the scheduler used. To actually force execution in one thread, a custom scheduler would be needed, rather than the default thread pool scheduler. (Or, if using custom awaitables and not `Task`s, no scheduler at all is needed and you can write single-threaded asynchronous code -- basically, pure continuations.)

Comment: @MindSwipe: Actually, some time ago, I had a problem with a Monitor that was released from another thread than it was entered (I know, I know, there was some good reason why I wasn't allowed to use a lock-statement ;) ). I was able to solve the issue by using a semaphore, but It was always bugging me, that I do not really understand when my code would switch to different threads...

Comment: @jeroenMostert: That sounds complicated, but also interesting, though... not that I really want to use it, but it's nice to understand these concepts. Do you have some links where these are described properly?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I remember reading a nice article by one of the people who know bunches about `async`/`await` where custom awaitables with no threading at all were demonstrated for educational purposes, but I can't find it now. Anything written by Stephen Cleary, Stephen Toub or Eric Lippert on the subject is worth reading, though. Search their blogs for "async" and it's bound to be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that in case of an existing SynchronizationContext the original thread will be used again after the await, if ConfigureAwait(false) is not called. That is not the topic of this question.

Well, no and yes.

No, `SynchronizationContext` does *not* necessarily mean "the same thread". It just means "the same context". If that context is the UI context, then that context does refer to the same thread (the UI thread). If that context is a thread pool context, then that context can refer to *any* thread pool thread.

And yes, that really is the topic of this question, because the current `SynchronizationContext` (or current `TaskScheduler` if there is no current `SynchronizationContext`) determines which thread the method resumes on.

> What are the particular cases when an async flow is continued in another thread?

At the point where an `await` needs to asynchronously yield, [it will capture its context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (`SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`). When the method is ready to be resumed, it is resumed on that context. Usually, this is either a UI context (which is tied to a specific UI thread) or the thread pool context (which can use any thread pool thread).

`ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` overrides that behavior and always schedules continuations on a thread pool thread.

Note that in the thread pool case, the `async` method may or may not resume on the same thread it started on. It doesn't necessarily mean a *different* thread pool thread - it can be any thread pool thread at all.

> Is it possible to force that all async methods in a call tree are extecuted in the same thread? (I don't need this, but just want to get the understanding, why that might not be possible...)

You can't *force* it, but you can make it the default behavior. You can create a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` (or `TaskScheduler`), and execute the asynchronous code in that. If you do that, then by default, `await` will resume on that same thread; but if it wants to, the asynchronous code can bypass that context just by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and then it would resume on a thread pool thread.

[`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) is an example of a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! That finally enlighted me 